# How to setup @RouteConfig in Dart

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-routing

Given the following

### .ts

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/',          name: 'root',      redirectTo: ['Home'] },
  { path: '/home',      name: 'Home',      component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/about',     name: 'About',     component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '/contact',   name: 'Contact',   component: ContactComponent },
  { path: '/protected', name: 'Protected', component: ProtectedComponent },
])
```

Using the same code in dart gives a lot of errors. What is the correct dart code? Adding a const for the list does not correct the error

Comment: Would be interresting what errors you got. I have only tried concrete classes instead of maps (`new Route(path: ...)` instead of `{...}`) but saw it mentioned that it is supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart you need to quote map keys

```
{ 'path': '/', 'name': 'root', 'redirectTo': ['Home'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  @RouteConfig( const [
    const Route(path: '/',          name: 'root',      redirectTo: ['Home']),
    const Route(path: '/home',      name: 'Home',      component: HomeComponent),
    const Route(path: '/about',     name: 'About',     component: AboutComponent),
    const Route(path: '/contact',   name: 'Contact',   component: ContactComponent),
    const Route(path: '/protected', name: 'Protected', component: ProtectedComponent)
  ])
```

Source: [Angular Cheat Sheet - dart](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/cheatsheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Correct one (without redirectTo which is not supported with Dart):

```
@RouteConfig( const [
    const Route(path: '/home',      name: 'Home',      component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true),
    const Route(path: '/about',     name: 'About',     component: AboutComponent),
    const Route(path: '/contact',   name: 'Contact',   component: ContactComponent),
    const Route(path: '/protected', name: 'Protected', component: ProtectedComponent)
])
```